# Limitar los elementos que puedan ver los usuarios en las vistas en Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, crud

Esta es la vista de posts de un blog para crear, editar, ver y eliminar.  Quiero restringir el botón de crear y eliminar para que un usuario con cierto id pueda ser el único en ver y usar estos botones.

Aqui coloco el codigo de la vista:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Lista de Entradas
                    <a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}" 
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">Crear</a>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="10px">ID</th>
                                <th>NOMBRE</th>
                                <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($posts as $post)                               
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $post->name }}</td>
                                <td width="10px">
                                <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">ver
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10px">
                                <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">editar
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10px">
                                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['posts.destroy', 
                                $post->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                                        Eliminar                                    
                                    </button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {{ $posts->render() }}
                </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Esto es lo que debe ver el usuario con cierto id al que se le permite ver los botones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y esto es lo que deben ver el resto de los usuarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, básicamente es evitar que los usuarios puedan crear o eliminar a excepción de un usuario en especifico con cierto id.

**Edit1:** Pude solucionarlo agregando este condicional en la vista:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == 29)

                    <a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}" 
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn 
btn-sm btn-primary pull-right"> Crear</a>

                    @endif
```

De esta forma solo el usuario con ese id en especifico puede crear. El mismo caso seria para eliminar.

Comment: La respuesta está en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication

Answer (score 1):

La implementacion simple que vos queres lograr se puede hacer así:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == 1 )
    //Mostrar botón
@endif
```

En lo personal implementaría una clase "Role" N a N con User.
Le asignaría roles a los usuarios y luego mostraría o no el botón en base a ese role, por ejemplo algo así:

```
@if(Auth::user()->tieneRole("Admin"))
    //Mostrar botón
@endif
```

En la cual tieneRole una función que tenes que crear en el modelo User que chequee que ese usuario tenga ese role.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) para Laravel.

Es un sistema de permisos y roles muy fácil y muy completo.

***Gestion de roles blade***

```
 @role('admin')
   //Cualquier contenido blade
 @endrole
```

**Gestion de permisos blade**

```
@permission('customer-list')
    //cualquier contenido blade
@endpermission
```

En la documentación tienes todo bien explicado.